# Switching to light tabs in firefox

Tags: firefox

Recently the default color for the tabs in Firefox has become a blackish grey with white text. This happened a year or two ago as well, and at the time I managed to get it back to my preferred color scheme by setting Firefox's theme to "light". However, as you can see, even though the theme is still light, the tabs are back to being black again.

Is there anyone here who has some idea what the issue might be, and what I can do to get back my preferred setup? That would be all the tabs being more or less the same as the active one is in the screenshot?

I'm using Firefox Quantum 65.0 (64-bit) if that matters.

[image]

Comment: This isn't an issue, it's normal. Same in my case. Though now-a-days people are attractive towards The Dark Mode ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this resource](https://support.mozilla.org/ro/questions/1184482), you can do it by going to the firefox menu ≡ > addons > themes panel

Comment: Yes, as mentioned I already did this the first time it happened, but switching the theme to light no longer works.